# Settings.Settings is updated to default values in C#

Tags: c#

I have the settings file in C# where I store the configuration parameters. So, I build the solution and install it in the system. The application creates an XML file user.config consisting of all the configuration parameters in :

`%userprofile%\appdata\local or %userprofile%\Local Settings\`

I made changes to the configuration through the application and save it by issuing the command

`Properties.Settings.Default.Save();`

When I restart the application, the configuration consists of the default values and not the updated values.

Any idea if I am missing something here.

[image]

Comment: By "restart", do you mean recompile + rerun? Does this change the version number of the app?

Comment: Do you want to `get` the updated values from your Settings?

Comment: No, Its not recompile. I close and start the application again from the Program Files Directory.

Comment: Are you sure that the `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();` line actually executes?

Comment: @spajce, Yes, I need the updated values. It consists of all the configuration parameters I would be using the application.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici, Yes It does, I can check the values being updated from the default values to the values that I set through the application. When I close the application and start again, the values are updated again, but this time, the default values.

Comment: After you have closed the application, does the contents of the settings file look correct?

Comment: Could you place a breakpoint after the `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();` line and observe the actual `user.config` file content to see if the new values are updated?

Comment: Please to follow the msdn instructions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @AlexFilipovici, Yes, the values would be updated when the application is closed as well. However when the application is started again, it loads the user.config with the default values.

Comment: Are you also calling `Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();` in your code?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici Yes, I do. But it is under if() which gets called only once when the installation is done. However I will check again if it is the cause.

Comment: If you call it before the `Save()` method, then it will revert your values to the previous ones.

Comment: I donot call Upgrade() at all actually. But still the values are being reverted to default values.

Comment: Could you check as early as possible in the code execution that `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)` returns the expected path to your `user.config` file?

Comment: Yes, it Returns `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local` the application creates the folder `SapnaEdu` within this structure

Answer (score 2):

> %userprofile%\appdata\local or %userprofile%\Local Settings\

This is what is fundamentally wrong about the question, this is not where the user.config file is stored.  The LocalFileSettingsProvider class (the default settings provider class) stores the user.config file in a directory with an unspeakable name, like C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1._Url_twchbbo4atpsvjpauzkgkvesu5bh2aul\1.0.0.0

The `twchbbo4atpsvjpauzkgkvesu5bh2aul` part of the name is produced by a hashing function that combines the program install location, program name, [AssemblyCompany] and [AssemblyProduct] to ensure that the directory is unique and will not clash with the user.config of another program.  And appending the [AssemblyVersion] so that different versions of the program won't clash.

You'll need to diagnose this problem by first finding the right user.config file back.  Start from the %appdata%\Local or %appdata%\Roaming directory.  Ensure that the Save() method actually saves, it won't if no setting was assigned a different value.  Use SysInternals' ProcMon utility to double-check all assumptions, you'll see your program accessing the file in the trace.

Answer (score 1):

What is the Scope of your settings? You cannot change Application Scoped settings like that from code.
Take a look at the settings designer.
[image]

You can read more about settings scope [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx).

Comment: The scope of the setting is `user`